# JQUERY why this field doesn´t change?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, calculated-field, jquery-calculation

i reused the code from every calculation in there but nothing. seems like the field that is listening never change.

```js
</div>
```

thnks for ur time

Comment: The `change` event only happens when the user changes the input, not when it's updated from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After set the Values you can trigger change event.

```
$("element").val("newValue").trigger('change');
```

this might help you.

Comment: thnks this is really helpful